# iframe refresh banner code NO PAGE REFRESH

Tags: iframe

how do i create a iframe refresh ads banner code NO PAGE REFRESH ,not adsense

example =>

```
<div align="center">
<iframe src ="http://www.1pars.com/ads/2.html" id="I1" 
name="I1" align="center" height="63" width="500" "border="0" 
frameborder="0"  scrolling="no" marginheight="1" 
marginwidth="1"><p>Your browser does not support 
iframes.</p>
```

Comment: Please indent code with four spaces.

Comment: I don't think I'm really grasping what your problem is. Can you elaborate on this a little bit further?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple as this:

```
<iframe src="../../../index.htm">
  <p>Your browser doesn't support frames. You can visit the site directly via
     <a href="../../../index.htm">this link</a>.</p>
</iframe>
```

The linked `index.html` needs to have this in its header:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15; URL=index.html">
```

Comment: Hallo jannis , ich spreche deutsch , wenn du mir weiter helfen kannst !!

Comment: Dear jnns
I speak german,
1-my banner code is ads banner it is not own image so i have not href=
2- i must set my banner code in chatroom file (chat,tpl.html)
Example code => 

<iframe src ="http://www.1pars.com/ads/2.html" id="I1" 

name="I1" align="center" height="63" width="500" "border="0" 

frameborder="0"  scrolling="no" marginheight="1" 

marginwidth="1"><p>Your browser does not support 

iframes.</p>
    
</iframe>

Answer (score 0):

The question is fairly generic; however, if you want to just have an iframe load a banner image, and then have that banner image refresh dynamically, the best choice to me would be an ajax request to the server to fetch your next image to use, and then insert the new source url into your image tag on the page.

Alternatively, your iframe banner page could contain some images on it, and some javascript to rotate between the predefined images.

However, without knowing a more complete issue, that's the best answer I can give.